# Prevent Body Scrolling with React Modal (iOS)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-hooks, react-modal

There a lot of threads online about how to lock the body especially on iOS, but I haven't found a good answer.

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Doesn't work on iOS.

My question is: how can I prevent Body Scrolling on iOS with `react-modal`?

Note: I found this package that it might work, but the problem is that I can't find a way to make it work with `react-modal` and hooks.

https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock

Any help?

Comment: Bad news: it's not a trivial one-liner to get that to work across different devices such as chrome desktop and mobile safari. Good news: plenty of packages do that for you, such as the aforementioned body-scroll-lock. There are bound to be react-modal alternatives that come with scroll lock built-in as well, so I'd suggest your look for a modal/scroll-lock package that works for you or look into the source code of a package like body-scroll-lock to try and understand how to code that yourself.